# How to establish or attach a console to running c++ application running on Linux to have user interaction like input-output

Tags: c++, unix, io, console

I have a C++ application which gets launched at boot time on Unix. Later when I log-in to the Unix machine, I would like to establish or attach a console, then run script which would set the input parameters to this c++ application. There are fixed like 10 parameters that need to be sent to the C++ application. Later once the C++ application processes it and then responds pass or fail which should be output on the same console.
All 10 parameters are needed at same time before the C++ application can start processing these parameters.

How to attach console to running application and send input parameters and receive output from application on the same console ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A more standard way of interacting with daemons is to supply a config file and send a signal like HUP to re-read it.  Output is generally in logs or similar.  Other approaches are to have a second program that _is_ run from the console which uses IPC to communicate with the daemon.

Comment: Why does the application get launched at boot time if it needs processing parameters to start?

Comment: Application has timing requirements and hence it is started at boot time.